# FOREIGN KEY Cascade Deletion No Action

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I'm working on creating a table using an Entity object and Code-First Migrations called `RegisteredEvents`. A `RegisteredEvent`  will have 1 `User` and 1 `Event`. Below are my `RegisteredEvents`, `User`, and `Event` classes.

```
public class RegisteredEvents
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public User User { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public string EventID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EventID")]
    public Event Event { get; set; }
}

public class Event : EntityData
{
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int HostUserID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("HostUserID")]
    public User HostUser { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

Whenever I try to do a migration with these class definition, I get the following error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_dbo.RegisteredEvents_dbo.Users_UserID' on table 'RegisteredEvents'
>   may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO
>   ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY
>   constraints.

I have seen recommendations to use the `modelBuilder` to set `WillCascadeOnDelete` to false, but it looks like you need to use something with `[Required]` set on it, which doesn't really apply here - since it's a dual primary key, both the event and the user are already required essentially.

Comment: Though I am not quite sure but I think making your foreign key nullable might turn off cascade delete. You can try using `Public int? UserID {get;set;}`  in class RegisteredEvents and then migrating it.

Comment: I ended up manually marking the DB Update script with `cascadeOnDelete: false`, but in regards to your comment, I don't want those fields to be nullable - you can't register for an event without saying what the event is, and who is registering.